# jquery selecting a element child then an attribute of that child

Tags: jquery, parent-child, attr

```
<object id="foo">
  <param value="bar1" name="foo1"></param>
  <param value="foo2" name="bar2"></param>
</object>
```

To get a value should the jquery be this?

```
$("#foo > param[name='bar2']").attr("value")
```

Doesnt seem to work for me.

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: if it's not working please show more context of how you are using it. The selector part seems fine

Comment: Your way should be working just fine. See  http://jsfiddle.net/qccm78LL/1/

Comment: On my case test I was using it on a live page in greasemonkey and that may have been the reason I was getting undefined. THanks all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#foo").find('[name="bar2"]').attr("value")
```

Or if the child element is an immediate child , you can use

```
$("#foo").children('[name="bar2"]').attr("value")
```

Comment: These are still going to target the same path as what OP has. If OP code isn't working why would these?

Comment: Your answer works, but it is conditional on only the attribute being correct and not the child element being param, is it possible to also make sure the child element is correct?

Comment: @Langerz use $("#foo").find('param[name=bar2]').attr("value")

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the code you provided, it worked fine; perhaps it is the version of jQuery you're using. Put

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

onto the page, and see if that makes the code you've written work.

Comment: I found using a more recent version, my code as I put up is working so I'm not crazy after all. :P Thanks.

Comment: I tried it with the oldest version of jQuery on jsfiddle, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/c3xf2q7v/